# Union Bit Fields

Tags: c++, c++11

I read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union:

> The union is only as big as necessary to hold its largest data member. The other data members are allocated in the same bytes as part of that largest member. The details of that allocation are implementation-defined, and it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.

I wonder why "it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written".

I wonder if the union has padding to enforce the order bits, will reading the member of the union that wasn't most recently written have defined behavior?

Example:

```
union {
uint8_t raw;
struct {
    uint8_t a : 1;
    uint8_t b : 2;
    uint8_t padding : 5;
};
} U;
```

Will it be okay to read U.raw correctly?

Comment: In your code, the `:1`, `:2` and `:5` bit-fields will overlap with each other - in no sense does `padding` provide padding of anything.  Perhaps you should google "type punning C++" and do some background reading.  *"I wonder why "it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written"."* - because the compiler can optimise more aggressively if it assumes variables are only written to through pointers or references to the same type (with a couple exceptions).

Comment: `The details of that allocation are implementation-defined` - A compiler may optimize away the code in such a way that it expects you to read data that is stored - for example, it may make optimizations such that data stored to `b` will be read only from `b` and not from `raw` or `a`. This is theoretical case. Also, remember that the layout of bitfields in memory aren't specified by the standard.

Comment: @TonyD thanks for your reply.  It is a bug in my example.  Fixed.  No more overlapping.

Comment: @ubuntugod the layout of bitfields in memory is probably not specified in C++ standard.  However, the C++ memory model is defined in the standard, and so I hope and wonder whether padding will enforce the order of bits.

Answer (score 1):

In the gcc x86 compiler I use, bit fields happen to be assigned from LSB to MSB (shown below).  The layout of "raw" is also shown.

```
  7                           0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|      padding      |   b   | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

  7                           0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|             raw               |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you set raw to 01000101b (0x45), then a == 1, b == 2 and padding == 8

```
  7                           0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|      padding      |   b   | a |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

However, what if the compiler assigned bit fields from MSB to LSB?

```
  7                           0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a |   b   |      padding      |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

  7                           0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|             raw               |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now, if you set raw to 01000101b (0x45), then a == 0, b == 2 and padding == 5.

```
  7                           0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| a |   b   |      padding      |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
```

If you understand how your compiler lays out unions and how it assigns bit fields, you can take advantage of this, but remember this is NOT portable.  I work in the embedded software field and we take advantage of this all the time.

Comment: It sounds like the layout of bits is static and compiler specific and compiler won't try to change the layout whenever the user accesses (both read and write).  Hence, in that case, if I write to U.a, U.b and U.padding and then read from U.raw, then I should get a compiler-specific behavior.  The "undefined behavior" in the standard is just giving the flexibility to the compiler implementers to layout the bits in the way they want.   Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Exactly.  Similarly, if you had a union of a **float** and **uint32**, you could write a floating point number (i.e., 1.0) and then read it as a unit32 (0x3f800000), but you would need to understand the low level format of the float.  Again, NOT portable, but interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard C++ it is not defined what happens if you access a member of a union that is not the same one most recently written.  This has nothing to do with what the members' types are, or their layout.

If your program does access a different member then you are relying on compiler-specific extensions.  In theory a compiler should document the fact if it does define union aliasing in C++.

Comment: Hi, I am reading C++ standard (version N3337).  Do you mind pointing out which section has the statement you mentioned?  I would like to read it again so that I don't miss the whole context.  Thanks!

Comment: N3337 is an old version now. N4140 is (almost) the latest published text, and the latest draft text can be found [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/).   See the first sentence of section [class.union]